# Wordpress loop to display posts from newest first, from a certain date

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm using a custom loop to bring up some posts, 3 at a time, after a certain date. It more or less works but the ordering is wrong, I want it to list newest first, so descending?

Using Ascending almost gets me what I want but obviously it's not the right order.:

Current post is Dec 12th 2012, 17th, 13th, 13th.

Using Descending I get the right order but it starts from the latest posts, not from the current post, so like this

Current post is Dec 12th 2012, Mar 26th 2013, 27th, 28th.

What I want is this:

Current post is Dec 12th 2012, 13th, 13th, 17th.

I can't get my loop to display the correct order, speaking of loop here's mine:

```
$args = array(
     'orderby' = > 'date', 
     'order' = > 'DESC', 
     'posts_per_page' = > 3, 
     'offset' = > $offset, 
     'category__in' = > $cat, 
     'post_status' = > 'publish',
     'date_query' = > array(array('after' = > $date)));
```

So at the moment this loop is descending like it's supposed to but it's not starting from the date of the current post, only ascending starts from the correct date, but it's not the order I want to display posts.

What's wrong with my loop arguments?

Answer (score 0):

So I just used some hackery instead and reversed the order of my loop:

```
$args = array('orderby' => 'date','order'=>'ASC','posts_per_page'=>3, 'offset' => $offset, 'category__in' => $cat,'post_status' => 'publish',
'date_query' => array(array('after' => $date ))); 
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
$array_rev = array_reverse($loop->posts);
 $loop->posts = $array_rev;
  while($loop->have_posts()) {
    $loop->the_post(); 
    get_template_part( 'sidebar-posts-template' );
} wp_reset_postdata();
```